# How can I modify SharePoint file properties or delete versions with Power Automate while another user has the file locked?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Is it possible to force update SharePoint file properties or delete versions when the file is being edited by another user (i.e. locked), using power automate or rest API

Tried to close locked file using power automate but could not do it